# Find covariance of matrix transformation

Tags: statistics, variance, covariance

I have a 2D random variable $X$ and $EX=(1,0)^T$ and

$
VX=
\begin{bmatrix}
4 && 4 \\
4 && 16
\end{bmatrix}
$

If $Y_1=X_1+2$ and $Y_2=X_2-X_1+1$, then how do I find the variance matrix for $Y$?

I have tried the following where I emitted the constants as my guess is they don't affect variance:
$Cov(Y_1,Y1)=Cov(X_1,X_1)=Var(X_1)=4$

$Cov(Y_2,Y_2)
=Cov(X_2-X_1,X_2-X_1)\\
=Cov(X_2,X_2-X_1)-Cov(X_1,X_2-X_1)\\
=Cov(X_2,X_2)-Cov(X_2,X_1)-Cov(X_1,X_2)+Cov(X_1,X_1)\\
=16-4-4+4=12
$

Variance=
$\begin{bmatrix}
4 && 0\\
0 && 12
\end{bmatrix}
$

But the result seems wrong because now they are no longer correlated just because of addition and/or subtraction

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Find a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ such that $Y=v+AX$ for some vector $v$ and apply the general rule: $$\mathsf{V}(v+AX)=A\mathsf{V}(X)A^T$$

Btw: I think that your result is correct.

It might well be that $X_1$ and $X_2-X_1$ are uncorrelated while $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not uncorrelated.